# php: Reordering an array and its subkeys

Tags: php, arrays, numerical, leaderboard

i am basically trying to make a leaderboard system. I need to put 2 types of data in my .yml file: the name of the player, and their score.

Here is a var dump:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
           string(10) "samueljh1_"
             [1]=>
                 int(3)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
           string(12) "samueljh1_54"
             [1]=>
                 int(1)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
           string(11) "samueljh1_1"
             [1]=>
                 int(8)
}
```

So, what I want to do is order this array, so that is is in numerical order - where the integers are.

Basically, converting the var dump above, to something like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
           string(11) "samueljh1_1"
             [1]=>
                 int(8)
      }
      array(2) {
        [1]=>
           string(10) "samueljh1_"
             [1]=>
                 int(3)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
           string(12) "samueljh1_54"
             [1]=>
                 int(1)
      }

}
```

If this isn't possible, are there any alternate ways to store this data?

Thanks A lot, - Sam.

Comment: First of all i have to say i feel like your array structure is more complicated than it should be. In php there are tons of array functions including sorting, i try to say if you can make more light your array these [native functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) will do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest using the player name as an associative key for the score value and simplifying the structure of the array, like so:

```
$testArray = array("samueljh1_" => 3, "samueljh1_54" => 1, "samueljh1_1" => 8);
```

This makes the array much simpler to parse and makes the data structure more closely resemble the relationship between the data you have. Then the function `arsort()`, which does reverse sorting, is what you're looking for:

```
arsort($testArray, SORT_NUMERIC); // $testArray is passed by reference

var_dump($testArray);
```

Yields

```
array(3) {
  ["samueljh1_1"]=>
  int(8)
  ["samueljh1_"]=>
  int(3)
  ["samueljh1_54"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: @Samueljh1 Updated this answer to use your sample data (and because originally I was sorting low-to-high). Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thats really helpful! I have one question though, i need to get the first 3 items in that array, - but not by the key name because this is stored somewhere else. Is there a way i can get the nth item in that array and get the name of the key? As its a leaderboard, i try to get the first value (like first place), once i have got the integer, how can i get the name of the key, that is holding that integer? I hope that makes sense! Cheers.

Comment: @Samueljh1 You could define a custom sort function to look into the nested array, like this: http://pastebin.com/x74VYYBM

Should produce output like this: http://pastebin.com/YsJJxvS6

Then you can access, for example, the top scoring player's name like this: `$testArray[0]["player"]`

Hope that helps you. :)

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll see what i can do with that :)

Comment: Ok, i have some issues: because i am trying to do usort in a class, i need to do $this->usort() rather than just usort() . How can i do that in the string format? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Never mind, i got it! its just array(new ClassName(),"function") :)

Comment: Omg! Thanks so much! It Works!! Your a real life-saver! :D